# Are local objects garbage-collected once they fall out of scope?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, vb6, garbage-collection

Say I have a function

```
Private Sub DoThing()
  Dim o As ComplexObject ' with possible backreference
  Set o = ComplexThing()
  Call DoStuff(o)
End Sub
```

My instinct tells me that `o` will be set to `Nothing` (and thus garbage-collected) once the function exits, but I can't find any documentation to confirm or refute this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as DoStuff() doesn't do any operation that would increase the reference counter of o, it's reference count will be come 0 and it's resources will be freed at that time.

Comment: Freed and deallocated in a deterministic manner.  There is no "garbage collection" involved here at all because it isn't necessary.  This isn't some weakly managed environment like .Net after all.  So the answer to the question is "no" but the question is improperly expressed.

Comment: +1 And here is the [VB6 documentation on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716330(v=vs.60).aspx)